# Merge without row multiplication in R

Tags: r, merge

I'd like to merge two different datasets in RStudio without row multiplication. That is, I'd like to keep all the rows of the first dataset (I use `merge(all.x=TRUE, ...)` for that), but I wouldn't like the rows of the first dataset to be multiplied in case second dataset has multiple values.

Example.

> Apples 4.99
>
> Oranges 3.89
>
> Bananas 2.65

&

> Apples red
>
> Apples green
>
> Oranges orange

So, after I've merged the two tables, I want to have fruits, prices, and colors, but I don't want to have Apples mentioned twice: I want to either just have one (either) color, or both merged together.

Does anybody know a solution? Thanks.

Comment: So I wonder if you actually tried `merge` before posting here?

Comment: Sure. So in this simplified example it would merge into Apples 4.99 red, Apples 4.99 green, Oranges 3.89 orange, Bananas 2.65 NA. But I don't want Apples mentioned twice, that's my problem.

Comment: So you want to put all the fruits in a single string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(fruit=c('Apples','Oranges', 'Bananas'), price=c(4.99,3.89,2.65))
d2 <- data.frame(fruit=c('Apples','Apples', 'Oranges'), color=c('red', 'green', 'orange'))
```

Note that I've named the columns, to help with the merge.  The first step is to remove the duplicated `fruit` names from `d2`:

```
d3 <- aggregate(color ~ fruit, data=d2, FUN=paste, collapse=' ')
```

Then perform a merge:

```
> merge(d1, d3)
    fruit price     color
1  Apples  4.99 red green
2 Oranges  3.89    orange
```

Comment: Actually, since my data is more complex than fruit, `aggregate` doesn't always solve it. I think it would be better to just select first instance, and drop other instances in the second table. For 100% same instances, I use `unique` function, but I'm not sure how to go about this instance.

Comment: You can use `aggregate` to get the first value as well: `aggregate(color ~ fruit, data=d2, FUN='[', i=1)`

Comment: Alright, I have to familiarize myself with regular expressions more. Thanks.